# Using JDBCInputFormat with variable tuple size (apache-flink)

Tags: java, apache-flink

I want to write a generic flink job in java, which can take any SQL-SELECT query, run it against a SQL-database and write it into a Elasticsearch index.

One of the problems I have to solve is creating a DataSource for a JDBC-Connection. I want to use the [JDBCInputFormat](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/io/jdbc/JDBCInputFormat.html). I followed the example in the [documentation data source](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/programming_guide.html#data-sources).

The problem is, the generic type `DataSource` type must be specified. And I can only use a `Tuple` type, because `JDBCInputFormat` generic type `OUT` extends `Tuple`. But I do not know at compile time which `Tuple` I will use.

1. Do I interpret something wrong?
2. Is there another jdbc `InputFormat` I can use?
3. Is there a way to specify `Tuple` as a generic type?

I use java 7 and apache-flink 0.10.2

I tried to use `Tuple25` with only Strings in it, but I get an exception.

Here follows code and then the exception.

```
DataSource<StringsTuple25> database = flink.createInput(
JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()//
  .setDrivername(getDatabaseDriverName())//
  .setDBUrl(getDatabaseUrl())//
  .setUsername(getDatabaseUsername())//
  .setPassword(getDatabasePassword())//
  .setQuery(getQuery())//
  .finish(), 
  StringsTuple25.typeInformation()
);
```

My `StringTuple25` class

```
public class StringsTuple25 extends
  Tuple25<String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static TypeInformation<?> typeInformation() {
    TypeInformation<String>[] types = new TypeInformation[25];
    Arrays.fill(types, STRING_TYPE_INFO);
    return new TupleTypeInfo<>(Tuple25.class,types);
  }
}
```

And I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Tuple size does not match columncount
  at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat.extractTypes(JDBCInputFormat.java:180)
  at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat.nextRecord(JDBCInputFormat.java:162)
  at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat.nextRecord(JDBCInputFormat.java:51)
  at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:169)
  at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:584)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicate, the number of attributes on your used `Tuple` type must match the number of selected columns in your SQL query. Furthermore, the data types for each attribute must match.

For example if you `SELECT id, name FROM ...` with `id` is `INTEGER` and `name` is `VARCHAR`, you would specify use `DataStream<Tuple2<Integer,String>>` (or specialize your own class `class MyResultType extends Tuple2<Integer,String>` and `DataStream<MyResultType>`) and provide a corresponding `TypeInformation`.

You can also go with generic `Tuple` type. Your stream would be `DataStream<Tuple>` (without specifying the number or types of attributes). However, for the `TypeInformation` you **need to know the number of attributes**.

```java
Tuple t = Tuple.getTupleClass(numberOfAttributes).newInstance();
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfAttributes; i++) {
    t.setField("", i);
}
TypeInformation<Tuple> typeInfo = TypeExtractor.getForObject(t);
```

Thus, you need to infer the number of selected attributes from you given arguments that define your SQL query.

Comment: But the number of column and the type of it depends on the SELECT-statement, which is provided by an argument. How can I resolve that? Do I need my own `InputFormat` for such a thing?

Comment: This solves my initially question, but now I get problems when running a `MapFunction` on it. I will try to use my own `InputFormat` class, which produce `Map<String, String>` instead of `Tuple`. It seems to integrate more with my idea of how to do it.